# EntityFramework 6.1.3 does not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4 on visual studio 2015

Tags: json, entity-framework-6

Any idea why I receive the following error after Nuget installing Entity framework 6.1.3?

> Error notice: "The dependency EntityFramework 6.1.3 in project foo bar
>   does not support framework .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4"

Here's my global.json (edited out personal data)

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": foo bar Class Library",
  "authors": [ "foo bar" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is that `dotnet5.4` in your json? Are you from the future?

Comment: @Fede, that is .Net Platform 5.4.   No sure which EF version supports this platform.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+5.4&oq=.net+5.4&aqs=chrome..69i57.2371j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=latest+.net+framework

@Fede  Latest .Net Framework version is 4.6   Lol

Answer (score 9):

I solved by deleting this line - "net451": { },, and then replacing "dotnet5.4" with "net451".

Comment: Worked like a charm. I guess it was just an old project template (since the codenames were renamed a few times).  I also had "net451" (for the full framework) which was replaced by "dnx451" (no side effects).

Comment: Can someone tell me how to prevent this in future projects, I had the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue with EF7 and I was able to solve it by changing dotnet54 to netcore50 in project.json in my EF library and every project depending on it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by just cutting the

`"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
 }`

dependencies into .Net4.51

```
"net451": {
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core": "2.2.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "2.2.1"
  }
```

Final Look

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "EMS.Identity Class Library",
  "authors": [ "SamuelA" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core": "2.2.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "2.2.1"
      }
    },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly fixed a similar issue by manually editing the project.json file.

**Note:** Let me mention that my solution is Asp.net 5.0 Web Application and is targeting DNX 4.5.1

It was:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "DataLayer Class Library",
  "authors": [ "local-admin" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
  }
}
```

I replaced the frameworks section and became:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "DataLayer Class Library",
  "authors": [ "local-admin" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue then i was able to solve it by deleting the obj folder of the particular project file.