# Your project is not referencing the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework.

Tags: .net, json, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am using VS 2015.

> Your project is not referencing the ".NETFramework,Version=4.5"
>   framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=4.5" in the
>   "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.

I am getting this error on my Data Access and Business Logic layers, shortly after adding to my MVC Layer. Things were building fine until then, but I don't know what triggered this error. Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "foo bar Class Library",
  "authors": [ "foo bar" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what I have tried:

1. Replacing "dotnet5.4" with "net451" (and deleting it) as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211191/entityframework-6-1-3-does-not-support-framework-netplatform-version-v5-4-on-vi).

Result is the same error.

2. Replacing "dotnet5.4" with "net45" and leaving the "net451". This results in a new error:

> Your project.json doesn't have a runtimes section. You should add
>   '"runtimes": { "win":{} }' to your project.json and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.

I tried doing as this error suggested and adding

```
"runtimes": {
    "win":  {}
  },
```

This got me this error, which I can't seem to move past:

> Your project.json doesn't list 'win' as a targeted runtime. You should
>   add '"win": {}' inside your "runtimes" section in your project.json,
>   and then re-run NuGet restore.

I've already added "win", and this is beginning to feel like a red herring. What am I doing altering the project.json directly, isn't NuGet handling this?

Comment: For the first part go to your project settings and set Target Framework to 4.5

Comment: It is set that way already.

Comment: @S.LovelandECY Did you get this resolved? I'm getting the same problem whether I use 4.5.1, 4.5.2 or 4.6 - All my projects are definitely all using the same framework version.

Comment: @S.LovelandECY you may want to consider changing the accepted answer given the disparity between votes between it and highest-voted answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually just figured out the problem. I ended up clicking on `Restore Nuget Packages` at the solution level and I managed to compile my `PCL` file, and then the rest of my solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43010272/5387794) is what was relevant for me.

Answer (score 207):

I had this same problem, and I ended up having to not only delete the contents of `bin` and `obj` folders, but also the `.vs` directory for the solution.

Comment: .vs was causing the issue for me

Comment: .vs wasn't necessary for me. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea how to thank you properly. I've been scratching my head for the most part of an hour trying to figure this one out. deleted all 3 and working like a charm. +1

Comment: I have a suspicion that this problem is caused by switching GitHub branches on my local development box. That is, I work in one branch and compilation creates numerous files which are not part of the repository. Then I checkout a different branch, and these non-repository files are still in place. Somehow they conflict with the newly checked out files.

Comment: @PhoeniceusAgelaius confirmed, this happened to me when switching between git branches where some of the projects had different nuget packages

Comment: This solution usually worked for me in the past, but today deleting files did not help. I eventually determined to rebuild the project from scratch by copying the everything methodically from one project to the other. Turns out that the ONLY difference between the two projects (other than the project GUID) is a `<TargetFrameworkProfile />`  in the broken project file. Removed it and _voila!_

Comment: Thank you . This worked for me too. I had to do both the steps. 1)Delete .VS 2)Delete "bin" and "obj" folders. I think the latter is more important.

Comment: Just deleting the obj folder was enough to resolve it for me

Comment: @Morvael which version of VS?

Comment: @ChrisR.Donnelly Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.0.3

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: bin/obj folders were the problem for me, even after a Clean from Visual Studio. Deleted these and then it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this did it, but how pathetic is this?

Comment: @MariusMatioc oh I agree.  The problem is VS state can easily get corrupted, and unfortunately the best solution is often to wipe that state.

Comment: how can windows devs stand all these VS shenanigans? Coming from a linux world where builds were generally 100% reproducible, this seems like next level insanity

Answer (score 132):

I had the same problem - this occurs still using Visual Studio 2017.3, which uses .csproj files instead of project.json. Interestingly, the error message still contains the text "project.json".

It appears the cause of this issue is a lock file or `obj\project.assets.json` file (depending on your version of VS) from a previous build, which is not removed during a clean, [as described here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/40369/view.html).

Manually deleting the `/obj` directory is a quick workaround.

If you have a "new" project (eg .NET Core or netstandard project created in VS 2017) and an "old" project in the same directory (eg .NET 4.6 project created in VS 2015), it appears they will continually fight because they both use the `./obj` dir in different ways. [More info here.](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5126).

The msbuild workaround is to make one of your projects use a different `obj` dir. I added this to my "old" csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Needed due to old project and new project in same directory: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5126 -->
  <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj_netfx\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This workaround works well with VS 2017, you saved me on time.

Comment: Ya that is a great explanation and answer, for our case it was .NET Framework 4.7 with .NET Standard 2.0 but the problem and solution is the same

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me mad since I don't have a project.json file in this project!

Comment: Great answer, I had to delete all `./obj` dirs in my solution (over 90) to resolve this issue.

Comment: Still a problem even in VS 2019. Thanks for solution!

Comment: Still a problem in 2020. The only way to solve it. `<IntermediateOutputPath>obj_netfx\</IntermediateOutputPath>` does not work or is not enough.

Answer (score 27):

I found that a rogue project.lock.json was causing this issue for me. Once I deleted the file, the problem went away.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/archive/project-json#projectlockjson) is some documentation on project.lock.json.

Some further advice would be to ensure that project.lock.json is ignored in your git ignore file, and to try a full git clean. Make sure you understand the implications of a Git clean before you do that though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after updating to Visual Studio for Mac 7.4 (build 1033):

```
Error: Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.
```

I don't have any json project files. The tips in here did not help either, so I had to find out the hard way that I had to install the lastest Android SDK (Oreo 8.1) in addition to my target SDK (Nougat 7.1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, but i've solved by adding proper nugget package resource at
`vs2017-->tools-->options-->Nugetpacakge manager--->updated` the proper package url.

Refer below image

[image]