# MonoAndroid Version 8.0 compilation error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, compiler-errors

I suddenly started getting this error on my Xamarin forms project

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/NuGet/Microsoft.NuGet.targets(184,5):

 error : Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.
```

I tried to add different references but couldn't solve the issue. So, I reset the files to the last commit which was working fine but even then, I am getting this error on my android project.

Comment: this issue is driving me crazy, I tested with other projects and they are working fine. Just this project is giving me issues.

I also branched to different commits to see if I did something on the way.

Comment: Please look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190601/your-project-is-not-referencing-the-netframework-version-v4-5-framework).

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT
 Thanks for your response. I have Visual Studio for Mac and I don't have the option to restore packages at the project level. I also don't have a project.json file. I am not sure where to find it.

Comment: Hi, have you installed the Android SDK Platform27? Take a look [here](https://qiita.com/Frog_woman/items/6164a3bf4bd175ccc764), the author also is using the Mac. And [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123743/xamarin-froms-onpropertychanged-from-another-page)

Comment: Thanks for your multiple responses. I really appreciate it. This shouldn't be connected to my issue but I am not facing the problem right now after updating MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , try clean and restore nuget packages 
if this don't solve the problem cleaning the nuget caches should solve , 
from tools>options>nuget package manager > clear all nuget cache and don't forget to put android 8 as target android version in project properties.

Comment: I don't have the option to clear Nuget cache on Visual Studio for Mac. Is there a CLI option for Mac?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: I followed this guide to clear the cache https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/6987/how-to-clear-nuget-cache

I am still getting the same error though. 
I am not sure how to target the android 8 version. But I tried different options on targeting framework such as 8.1 , 8.0,..

Answer (score 3):

I did the following that worked for me:

1. Build > Clean All
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Got to solution Directory > in each Project and delete **bin** and **obj** folder
4. Open Visual Studio
5. Build > Rebuild All

Its like food , if you skip a step it will not work.